# Heatmap in R with raw values

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, heatmaply

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("3454","345","5","348","567","79"),
                 clas1 = c(1, 0, 5, NA, NA, 4),
                 clas2 = c(4, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0),
                 clas3 = c(1, NA, 0, 5, 5, 5), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would like to create a heatmap, with patient ID in the x axis and clas1, clas2 and clas3 in the y axis. The values represented in the heat map would be the raw value of each "clas". Here I post a drawing of what I would like

[image]

I apologise because I don't have available more colours to represent this, but this is only an example and any colour scale could be used.
An important thing is that I would like to distinguish between zeros and NAs so ideally NAs have their own colour or appear in white (empty).

I hope this is understandable enough.

But any questions just ask

Many thanks!

Comment: I see you already picked a "chosen" answer, but I've added another answer that showcases several great options (that are, IMHO, better than using ggplot2 code directly. Which is why these packages exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Preparing the data

I'll give 4 options, in all four you need to assign the rownames and remove the id column. I.e.:

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("3454","345","5","348","567","79"),
                 clas1 = c(1, 0, 5, NA, NA, 4),
                 clas2 = c(4, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0),
                 clas3 = c(1, NA, 0, 5, 5, 5), stringsAsFactors = F)
rownames(df) <- df$PatientID
df$PatientID <- NULL
df
```

The output is:

```
> df
     clas1 clas2 clas3
3454     1     4     1
345      0     1    NA
5        5     0     0
348     NA     3     5
567     NA     1     5
79       4     0     5
```

## Base R

With base R (decent output):

```
heatmap(as.matrix(df))
```

[image]

## gplots

With gplots (a bit ugly, but many more parameters to control):

```
library(gplots)
heatmap.2(as.matrix(df))
```

[image]

## heatmaply

With heatmaply you have nicer defaults to use for the dendrograms (it also organizes them in a more "optimal" way).

You can learn more about the package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmaply/vignettes/heatmaply.html).

### Static

Static heatmap with heatmaply (better defaults, IMHO)

```
library(heatmaply)
ggheatmap(df)
```

[image]

Now with colored dendrograms

```
library(heatmaply)
ggheatmap(df, k_row = 3, k_col = 2)
```

[image]

With no dendrogram:

```
library(heatmaply)
ggheatmap(df, dendrogram = F)
```

[image]

### Interactive

Interactive heatmap with heatmaply (hover tooltip, and the ability to zoom - it's interactive!):

```
library(heatmaply)
heatmaply(df)
```

And anything you can do with the static ggheatmap you can also do with the interactive heatmaply version.

[image]

Comment: Great answer with so many options! Upvoted!

Comment: Hi Tal, one quick question. what can I do to define the color scale range? I want to compare diffent heatmaps so I need all the colour scales to go from 0:100 - Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Lili - it depends on which heatmap option you decide to use. Please write a new question on this, relating to the specific implementation you care about (and a simple self contained example). Thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68136213/change-range-scale-in-a-ggheatmap.    thanks so much!!! :) (basically I am representing percentages, and I want to compare 2 different heatmaps where one goes from 0% to 100% and other goes from 0% to 60%. So I want the scale of both to represent colours from 0 to 100%

Answer (score 4):

```r
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("3454","345","5","348","567","79"),
                 clas1 = c(1, 0, 5, NA, NA, 4),
                 clas2 = c(4, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0),
                 clas3 = c(1, NA, 0, 5, 5, 5), stringsAsFactors = F)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% pivot_longer(!PatientID) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= PatientID, y = name, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Anil, Unfortunately this does not work ( it doesn't give me any error either. But it doesn't produce the plot)

Comment: @Lili, that's why I showed on reprex.  It means error is somewhere else and not in the code.  Try first on the sample data.

Comment: Not sure what happened, but switched on and off and now it works! beautiful plot, thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R option with ``heatmap`

```
heatmap(t(`row.names<-`(as.matrix(df[-1]), df$PatientID)))

# Which is like
# x <- as.matrix(df[-1]
# row.names(x) <- df$PatientID
# heatmap(t(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you thomas, same with the one below... :( it doesn't give me errors but it doesn't produce the plot either.

Comment: @AnilGoyal It gives the row names to the matrix. I also upvoted yours, which is a nice plot.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

[image]

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("3454","345","5","348","567","79"),
                 clas1 = c(1, 0, 5, NA, NA, 4),
                 clas2 = c(4, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0),
                 clas3 = c(1, NA, 0, 5, 5, 5), stringsAsFactors = F)


# named vector for heatmap
cols <-  c("0" = "white",
           "1" = "green", 
           "2" = "orange", 
           "3" = "yellow", 
           "4" = "pink",
           "5" = "black",
           "99" = "grey")
labels_legend <- c("0" = "0",
                   "1" = "1", 
                   "2" = "2", 
                   "3" = "3", 
                   "4" = "4", 
                   "5" = "5",
                   "99" = "NA")

df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("clas"),
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(PatientID = factor(PatientID, levels = c("3454", "345", "5", "348", "567", "79")))

ggplot(
  df1, 
  aes(factor(PatientID),  factor(names))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill= factor(values))) +
  # geom_text(aes(label = values), size = 5, color = "black") + # text in tiles
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = cols, 
    breaks = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "99"),
    labels = labels_legend,
    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"),
    drop = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme(line = element_blank(),
        title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom")
```