# change range scale in a ggheatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scale, heatmap

I would like to change the scale in the following heatmap in order to compare different heatmaps:

[image]

**Currently my biggest number is 60, and I would like this scale of colours to be from 0:100**

the code used is the following:

```
rownames(df) <- df$Status
df$Status <- NULL
df

library(heatmaply)
ggheatmap(df)
```

I am representing percentages, and I want to compare 2 different heatmaps where one goes from 0% to 100% and the other goes from 0% to 60%. So I want the scale of both to represent colours from 0 to 100% in order to make better visual comparisons (otherwise, it can be a bit misleading)

I don't seem to have found this information in the CRAN guide: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggheatmap/ggheatmap.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `+ scale_fill_viridis_c(limits = c(0, 100))`

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work :(  would it be ggheatmap(df) + scale_fill_viridis_c(limits = c(0, 100)) ? it says Error: Cannot use `+.gg()` with a single argument. Did you accidentally put + on a new line?